# Refresh the data in bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

The idea is that I want to refresh the data in the bar chart, not to update the previous data. Is there any method used to wipe out the previous data of the chart and apply the new one?

I have the following code:

```
if len(results_tfifg) >= 1: 
    plt.bar(*zip(*zip(count(), results_tfifg.values())))
    plt.title("TF IDF Chart")
    plt.xticks(*zip(*zip(count(0.4), results_tfifg.keys())))
    plt.xlabel("Word")
    plt.ylabel("TF*IDF")
    self.tf_idf_canvas.draw() 
else:
    fig = plt.figure()  
    #append chart to form (Vbox)
    self.tf_idf_canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)  # a gtk.DrawingArea
    self.tf_idf_chart_vbox.pack_start(self.tf_idf_canvas)
    self.tf_idf_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.tf_idf_canvas, self.tf_idf_chart_vbox)
    self.tf_idf_chart_vbox.pack_start(self.tf_idf_toolbar,False,False)
```

Comment: Check out [`plt.cla()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.cla), which clears the contents of the Axes.

Comment: yes, thank you very much. Submit it like an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`plt.cla()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.cla) function should provide what you're looking for, as it clears the contents of the current axes.